# 2 Node Cluster not replicating data

Tags: cassandra, elassandra

Running elassandra 5.5.0.18 (cassandra 3.11.2)

I have setup a test cluster containing of 2 nodes. RF = 2. I would expect both nodes to have the same data after bootstrap.

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  xxx.xxx.2.40   1.31 MiB   256          100.0%            388acf50-96c0-4294-938f-be56437bbf82  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.0.236  2.8 MiB    256          100.0%            8eed1e55-1b58-4599-a021-82b6852875aa  rack1
```

When I add data to node1, i see it being replicated to node2 (cqlsh directly to node). But node2 has only fresh data, data from node1, which has been there before the bootstrap process, is not replicated.

I tried running nodetool repair, but it fails with the following error message

```
Validation failed in /xxx.xxx.0.236 (progress: 0%)
[2018-06-27 13:49:19,438] Some repair failed
[2018-06-27 13:49:19,440] Repair command #1 finished in 9 seconds
error: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2018-06-27 13:49:19,438] Some repair failed
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2018-06-27 13:49:19,438] Some repair failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.RepairRunner.progress(RepairRunner.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.progress.jmx.JMXNotificationProgressListener.handleNotification(JMXNotificationProgressListener.java:77)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.dispatchNotification(ClientNotifForwarder.java:583)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.doRun(ClientNotifForwarder.java:533)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.run(ClientNotifForwarder.java:452)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$LinearExecutor$1.run(ClientNotifForwarder.java:108)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this? Seeing it now on my STG cluster.

Comment: Actually I was able to fix this. Unfortunately i cannot tell how. After some erraneos starting / restarting of nodes and repairs it started to work. You should try to do a full repair, if I remember right, there were some problems with one of the tables.